# [MetaplexError]: Failed to Send Transaction

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, metaplex-js, devnet

I'm using the Metaplex JS SDK on **devnet** and trying to update an NFT with the following call:

```
const response = await metaplex
        .nfts()
        .update({
            nftOrSft: nft,
            name: "New Name",
        })
        .run();
```

But receiving the following error:

```
FailedToSendTransactionError [MetaplexError]: Failed to Send Transaction
>> Source: RPC
>> Problem: The transaction could not be sent successfully to the network.
>> Solution: Check the error below for more information.

Caused By: AggregateError: All promises were rejected

    at RpcClient.parseProgramError (<redacted-path>/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/plugins/rpcModule/RpcClient.mjs:179:14)
    at RpcClient.sendTransaction (<redacted-path>/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/plugins/rpcModule/RpcClient.mjs:51:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RpcClient.sendAndConfirmTransaction (<redacted-path>/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/plugins/rpcModule/RpcClient.mjs:72:23)
    at async TransactionBuilder.sendAndConfirm (<redacted-path>/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/utils/TransactionBuilder.mjs:131:22)
    at async <redacted-path>/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/utils/Task.mjs:58:23
    at async Disposable.run (<redacted-path>/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/utils/Disposable.mjs:22:14)
    at async eval (<redacted-path>/updateNFT.ts:48:22)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./utils/api/apiHandler.ts:164:9)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./utils/api/handlers/apiHandler.ts:16:36) {
  key: 'metaplex.errors.rpc.failed_to_send_transaction',
  title: 'Failed to Send Transaction',
  problem: 'The transaction could not be sent successfully to the network.',
  solution: 'Check the error below for more information.',
  source: 'rpc',
  sourceDetails: undefined,
  cause: [AggregateError: All promises were rejected],
  logs: undefined
}
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Which RPC are you using? probably not available?

Comment: @ConciseLabs its a quicknode RPC. But other calls like `findByMint()` and `mint()` are working properly, just seeing this error with `update()`